# On-screen Keyboard manipulation metro

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I faced an interesting but tough(as for me) problem. I have a requirement for Windows metro-style application to invoke keyboard with numeric layout activated for some specific TextBoxes. After some research I found it hard to even show/hide that keyboard by request not talking about such layout manipulation. So my question is how can I activate specific layout for on-screen keyboard(like numeric or smilies layout) in Windows Metro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this post may not give you complete answer for your question, but to activate numeric keyboard for textboxes you can use below code

```
TextBox.InputScope = new InputScope
            {
                Names =
                {
                    new InputScopeName(InputScopeNameValue.Number)
                }
            };
```